# Google anayltics.js moved to external js file works, but gtag.js doesn't

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

For years I have had the Google Universal Analytics snippet in an external js file. It of course had to be converted to use it there. I am now trying to do the same thing with the newer Google Analytics 4 (gtag) snippet. So far, the data collection in Google Analytics is not happening. I DID test the snippet in the header first, and it works that way.

Here is the snippet as provided by Google, which is supposed to go in your head section:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=myGtagID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'myGtagID');
</script>
```

Here is the call that is already in each web page in their head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    window.onload=function(){
        analytics();
    }
    //-->
</script>
```

Here is the code inside my external js file.:

```
function analytics(){

  /* Universal Analytics property (analytics.js) - OLD CODE WHICH WORKS */
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'myUA_ID']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
    
  /* Google Analytics 4 property (gtag.js) - NEW CODE NOT WORKING */
  gtag.push(['js', new Date()]);
  gtag.push(['config', 'myGtagID']);

 (function() {
    var ga4 = document.createElement('script'); ga4.type = 'text/javascript'; ga4.async = true;
    ga4.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=myGtagID';
    var t = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga4, t);
    })();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GA4 currently doesn't work with the file:// protocol, only http:// and https://

Are you using file:// protocol in Cordova, for example? If so, GA4 will block analytics.

Comment: Thank you Flyingkiwi. I am using https.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution https://www.opinions.co.il/ogdan/loading-google-analytics-in-external-js-file/

I changed the variable name to `script_tag`, put the code inside a self-invoking function, and it seems to work.

```
(function(){
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=YOUR_ID';
    document.head.appendChild(script_tag);
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    
    gtag('config', 'YOUR_ID');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just took another look at your code. It appears you are attempting to use GA4 just like you used GA3. The 2 are not interoperable and don't share the same methods and properties. GA4 is a completely new analytics product from Google.

Please refer to the documentation from Google for more details.

Comment: I did, and they want the code IN each html page, which isn’t my preference. Oh well.

Comment: Do you mean you want the code in an external JS file? That's totally possible. Please post code if you want assistance.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The code is in my original post.